# How can I pass label value as variable for if else case?

Tags: javascript, html, css

im a beginner in writing codes and i'm learning javascript by creating a simple escape room game.
My idea is that when a player enters a 3 digit code that will unlock the door to escape, here is my code for it:

in html:

```
<form id="sifra">
<label><input name="text" /></label>
<button type="button" onclick="forma()">enter pass</button>
</form>
```

in js:

```
function forma() {

var x = document.getElementById("sifra");
if(x === 847) {
alert("door is unlocked");
} else {
alert("wrong pass");
}
}
```

Can you help me because this code doesn't work, thanks

Comment: You are not accessing the input element; you are not accessing its `value` property;  that input element will always have a string as its value.
`var x = document.querySelector("#sifra input").value; if (x === "847")`

Comment: tyvm that solved the problem